# sql track lack of record for a certain person upon inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that goes this way but I am wondering if there is a better way to do rather than the below attempt?

List the credit balance of all members who have less than 50 credits in their CreditBalance and  have not done any transactions in the year 2018 .

```
SELECT m.CreditBalance
FROM Member m 
INNER JOIN CreditCard cc
ON m.MemberID=cc.MemberID
INNER JOIN CreditDebitTrans cdt
ON cc.CardNo=cdt.CardNo
WHERE (cdt.TransDateTime  != DATEPART(Year,2018) 
AND
m.CreditBalance<50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This filters only on the transactions in the range, then the cdt.CardNo is null (since that's the join criteria) will means there's on cdt records in that range.

```
SELECT m.memberid, m.CreditBalance
FROM Member m 
INNER JOIN CreditCard cc
ON m.MemberID=cc.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CreditDebitTrans cdt
ON cc.CardNo=cdt.CardNo and cdt.TransDateTime>='2018-01-01' and cdt.TransDateTime<'2019-01-01'
WHERE cdt.CardNo Is Null and m.CreditBalance<50
group by m.memberid, m.CreditBalance
```

Comment: Hi can you explain more on cdt.CardNo IS NULL ?

Comment: so,since its a left outer join, the joined content with no records...all the fields in those tables will come back with nulls...since card number is a non null field (safe to assume)...so check for it being null means we have no creditdebittrans records

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is to create a subquery in the where clause. But it is almost the same what you already did:

```
SELECT 
    m.CreditBalance
FROM 
    Member m 
WHERE   
    m.CreditBalance<50
    AND m.MemberID NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            cc.MemberID
        FROM
            CreditCard cc
        INNER JOIN      
            CreditDebitTrans cdt
        WHERE   
            cdt.TransDateTime = DATEPART(Year,2018) 
    )
```

Comment: hi , shouldnt it be cdt.TransDateTime = DATEPART(Year,2018) in this case as you have used NOT IN?

Comment: So, I just posted another answer below using `EXISTS`, but then I realized that everyone else is using `DATEPART` in a way that I've never seen before. Normally the second parameter is a date of some kind. Wouldn't passing 2018 into the `DATEPART` function evaluate to a year that's very far in the past (and would likely never match a transaction)?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `EXISTS` in this type of situation.

```
SELECT m.CreditBalance
FROM Member m
WHERE
    m.CreditBalance < 50
    -- There are no transactions for the member in 2018:
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM CreditCard cc
            INNER JOIN CreditDebitTrans cdt ON cdt.CardNo = cc.CardNo
        WHERE cc.MemberID = m.MemberID
            AND cdt.TransDateTime >= '2018-01-01'
            AND cdt.TransDateTime < '2019-01-01'
    );
```

Comment: This will be better `cdt.TransDateTime >= '2018-01-01' and cdt.TransDateTime < '2019-01-01'`

Comment: @Pரதீப் Are you thinking it would optimize better?

Comment: `DATEPART` will make the query non sargable.

Comment: @Pரதீப் Thanks! You are correct. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Somehow I always thought that SQL Server had some sort of optimization here. To be honest, I typically do use a range and try to stray away from function calls as much as possible.